# Security: Form Submission + javascript/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

Question:

What is best practice for form submissions while keeping in mind security?

This may be a n00b question but I'm concerned that people might be able to alter some data as its being submitted. Take my example:

I have a form that has a hidden input that stores a user's unique Facebook ID. I take that Facebook ID and create a user account from it. If I use jQuery, won't some users be able to change the data being posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just as safe as a regular form post. Both methods can be hijacked and data injected. The key is how your server side scripts validate the data alongside authentication, session, anti forgery tokens etc

Comment: See comment above: There's no way to prevent users from sending an invalid facebook ID other than what's currently in the session?

Comment: I would not put an important id inside a hidden field with no encryption. I would store that value encrypted in a session cookie

Answer (score 2):

Users will always be able to post whatever data they like to your server. You can't do anything to change that with javascript. With a decent browser it's easy to find hidden form fields, unhide them, and put whatever you want in them. A more skilled user can craft an http post by hand and send whatever they like. Security must be done on the server, not on the client.

Comment: So there's no way to prevent them from sending over an invalid FB Id?

Comment: Nope, other than checking facebook somehow to see if it exists on their site.